# How can I automatically indent on new lines?

Tags: indentation, ide

I work on projects with varying levels of indentation. In many of these projects, because of how the files are typically structured, most lines are indented at least two levels (such as methods in Java files).

This would mean that creating a new line when on a line line

```
public void something () {
```

Would bring my cursor to the next line, automatically indented in, like

```
public void something () {
    [cursor]
```

While I can hit the tab key a few times on a new line to get it to line up, is there a better way of doing this (possible automatically)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This can be done using a combination of the `autoindent` option and the `filetype` plugin.

The `autoindent` option will copy your current indentation when creating a new line. So if your current indentation level is 4 when you start the new line, the cursor will be moved to the same indentation level on the next line.

In your `~/.vimrc` file, you would put

```
set autoindent
```

You can use the `filetype` plugin as well to automatically determine the next indentation level based on the file type.

You can enable this on the fly with

```
:filetype indent on
```

Or, in your `~/.vimrc` file you would put

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Which will automatically determine the indentation based on the file type.

Answer (score 8):

Use `:set cindent` (`:set cin` for short) or `:set smartindent` (`:set si` for short).  If your line ends in an opening brace, and you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the following line will automatically be indented one additional level.  (This is better than `:set autoindent`, which merely indents the next line at the *same* level.)  `cindent` is better tailored to C-like languages, while `smartindent` is more versatile for use with other programming languages.

The amount and type of indentation is controlled by `:set shiftwidth=…`, `:set tabstop=…`, and `:set expandtab`.

Comment: `'smartindent'` is deprecated, so that's not the best choice. It has been replaced by `'cindent'` and `'cinoptions'` for C-like languages.  In general, though, file type indenting is the way to go, with `'autoindent'` as a fallback.

Comment: @jamessan `smartindent` isn't deprecated, but `cindent` is worth noting. I've updated the answer. (Thanks!)

Comment: I'd also recommend you taking a look at http://editorconfig.org/  . There's of course a plugin for vim (and many other editors) and it's a great way to keep your editor defaults on your VCS

Answer (score -1):

At bottom of the file, I'm using:

```
# vim: ts=2 sw=2 sts=2 sr noet st ai si
```

For example `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM centos-7
RUN ...
CMD ...

# vim: ts=2 sw=2 sts=2 sr noet st ai si
```

If you want keep the indentation only, use `# vim: st ai si`